# getline() not reading first lines

Tags: c++

I am c++ beginner and this is for school..

I am trying to read a file about 28kb big. The program works but it doesnt print the first 41 lines. It works fine with a smaller file. 
At first i was reading into a char array and switch it to strings. 
i also tried changing the log buffer but it apparently it should be big enough..
I feel like this should be very simple, but just cant figure it out..

Any help will be greatly apreciated..
Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cerrno>

using namespace std;

struct espion
{
    char nom[30];
    char pays[20];
    char emploi[29];

};


int main()
{
    const int MAX_NOM = 30, MAX_PAYS = 20, MAX_EMPLOI = 29;
    char nomFichier[50] = "espion.txt";



    ifstream aLire;
    aLire.open(nomFichier, ios::in|ios::binary);

    if(!aLire.is_open()){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    std::string infoEspion;


    while(aLire)
    {
        infoEspion.clear();
        std::getline(aLire, infoEspion);
        cout << infoEspion ;

    }

    aLire.close();


    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: How many characters long are the lines? If at least one of them are greater than `std::string::max_size()` the extraction will fail.

Comment: Maybe `getline` works correctly, but some characters are lost when you print to `cout`. Try summing `infoEspion.size()` for all lines and see if it matches the file size. If it does, than `getline` could read your input correctly.

Comment: Please check each I/O operation (open, getline, close) for error, and make your program abort on error. Once done, update your question explicitly stating that there were no I/O errors.

Comment: You could use a *debugger* and place a breakpoint after the `getline`.  View your string variable and verify that the text was read correctly.

Comment: Unrelated: `std::getline()` clears the string initially so there's no need for `infoEspion.clear()` beforehand. Also, the input operation (the `std::getline()` call) should go directly into the parameters of the `while()` loop. Otherwise it will allow an extra unwanted read.

Comment: So after following all of your advices i found out the code was working fine, the problem was i was not adjusting the right buffer.. so ya problem solved, but i feel very silly..

Comment: Thanks for all the quick replies :-)

Answer (score 0):

From the system("pause"), it looks like you're running on Windows. With ios::binary, the end-of-line marker is not translated, and the cout << infoEspion; statement prints these "raw" lines in such a way that all of the lines are written on top of each other. (More specifically, each line will end with a return but no newline, so the cursor goes back to the start of the same line after executing each cout statement.) If you take out the ios::binary, you will echo all of the input on a single, very long line.  Changing the statement to cout << infoEspion << endl; will echo all of the lines.